# What is the best tool to replace certain parts of a string?

Tags: regex, string, replace, full-text-search, str-replace

I have some html files which I want to re-structure, something like this :

convert this:

```
<code>echo "hello world";</code>
```

to this:

```
[php]echo "hello world";[/php]
```

I know I can find / replace with notepad, but I would like to use a tool (preferrably online) where I can convert `x1-abc-y1` to `x2-abc-y2` , by choosing the x1,x2,y1,y2 parameters.

Do you know anything with this functionality ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

sed is the tool for the job!

```
$ echo "<code>echo "hello world";</code>" | sed 's/<\(\/\?\)code>/[\1php]/g'
[php]echo hello world;[/php]
```